# How to make trigger selective in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, game-engine, game-physics

I can't seem to make my trigger function work only for a specific group or object in unity. Plus it activates whenever I hit play which is an issue.

Comment: try to give a detailed information about your question. Add your code , what issue your facing? , where your blocking? , what you tried so far? like the way you have to ask your question. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you explain a bit further what you mean and show what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Tags](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) and [Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) pages on the Unity Docs, they should provide you with everything you need. The basic gist is that you can group a bunch of Game Objects by tagging them (or adding them to a layer). Then later when you are interacting with a Game Object or behaviour, you can check to see if it belongs to a certain group.

Below is a simple example of checking an Object's tag:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Fruit"))
    {
        Debug.Log("You've found a piece of fruit!");
    } else {
        Debug.Log("You've found something else :(");
    }
}
```

Good luck!